# Crashlytics doesn't upload mapping file with apk-splits

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics

We recently switched to apk splits (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits) in favor of build flavors, but the dexguard mapping file is no longer being uploaded.
Something I noticed is that the step injectCrashlyticsMappingFileId is only executed once, but there are 4 mapping files generated.
using: com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.1

```
android {
  splits {
    abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should upload bundle, it already contains mapping file, and auto feature of split apks on base of abi, user local etc.

Comment: @AbdurRehman let's just say app bundles are not an option for us (at least not yet)

Comment: then generate full apk including all abis, get mapping file, upload this mapping file, and again generate splitted apks upload these apks, I mean: mapping file remain same for all abis!

Comment: @AbdurRehman mapping file is definitely not the same for all abis! (at least not guaranteed) also: how would i upload the mapping manually, I can work it out as soon as i would see how i can manually upload it